# how to send datetime format from android to web service

Tags: java, android

I want to send dateTime from android to webservice with `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` format? How can I do?

I wrote these code to get date, it is ok.

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    String dDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

This method sends information to webservice.it works until `response.toString();`, but while `response.toString()` works, it gives error `invalid dateTime`.

```
private void _GetOrder(String sUsername, String sPassword, String sDeviceID, String sCustomer, String dDate){
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo sUsernameInfo = new PropertyInfo();
        sUsernameInfo.setName("sUsername");
        sUsernameInfo.setValue(sUsername);

        PropertyInfo sPasswordInfo = new PropertyInfo();
        sPasswordInfo.setName("sPassword");
        sPasswordInfo.setValue(sPassword);

        PropertyInfo sDeviceIDInfo = new PropertyInfo();
        sDeviceIDInfo.setName("sDeviceID");
        sDeviceIDInfo.setValue(sDeviceID);

        PropertyInfo sCustomerInfo = new PropertyInfo();
        sCustomerInfo.setName("sCustomer");
        sCustomerInfo.setValue(sCustomer);

        PropertyInfo dDateInfo = new PropertyInfo();
        dDateInfo.setName("dDate");
        dDateInfo.setValue(dDate);

        request.addProperty(sUsernameInfo);
        request.addProperty(sPasswordInfo);
        request.addProperty(sDeviceIDInfo);
        request.addProperty(sCustomerInfo);
        request.addProperty(dDateInfo);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        new MarshalDate().register(envelope);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            httpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            _GetOrderResult = response.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
```

Comment: does `dDate` get filled correctly with the proper string?

Comment: have you check your webservice. does it accepting the date as string format or in date format.

Comment: it is date format in the webservice

Comment: yeah,filled with the proper string

Comment: What are you trying to do with the date? If you're not going to display it back, may I suggest using `System.currentTimeMillis()`? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()

Comment: @user3096003 have you got the solution..I have also got the same problem..